# How to search items in firebase through code

Tags: android, firebase

I want to make medstore app. In it i made one option category for "all items". So no problem there, because i will fetch all items from firebase through recycler view.

I am inserting items in firebase through admin app.

Now the problem is that i want to categorised all items like

```
Fitness, ayurvedic, Homeopathic
```

So i have two options to do so .

1. I will make another node for in firebase for it .like Seprate node of ayurvedic ,seprate for fitness.

   And all items have many properties like

   ```
   Name, price , description, stock etc
   ```

   I guess it's not a good way beacuse it will consume more space unnessarily more than once.

   Because there is already one node for " all items " .

   So one item will cosume two space one in "all items" and other in "ayurvedic".

   Or
2. I will just put the " key " of items in specific node .not a full detail.

   And recycler view goes to main position(at node "all items" ) of items by seeing its key and will fetch all data like price from it.

   But how can i do so ?

And can anyone will explain me please which one is the best way to do?

Comment: What exactly would you like to use, Firestore or the Realtime Database?

Comment: @AlexMamo Realtime database

Comment: So to understand better, you ask if it's better to have different nodes for different types of products or a single node that contains all products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a "category" field in each item. So that if you add a new item in the "all items" node, the item has its own unique category.

In the client side, you can add a filter functionality. If the user filters by fitness, then query all items with category equal to fitness.

Something like

```
rf.orderByChild("category").equalTo("Fitness");
```

Now you can get all the items and you can also get specific categories without consuming extra storage.

[Here is a guide on querying real-time database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)

Comment: Thank you Brain Gachugu but then there will be problem I'm recyclerview. Then how can i show all items in one recyclerview?

Comment: @Fussycat You can add a valueEventListener without orderByChild on "all_items" node. This will load all the items. When the user filters by category, let's say "Fitness", you perform another query with orderByChild like above.

Comment: Ok..tx @Brian Gachugu got it .

Comment: Will be it valid if i want to add one item in multiple category?

Comment: @Fussycat I would suggest using cloud firestore for this. You can have an array field in each item called "categories" and then you can use whereArrayContains("categories", "fitness"). This way, you can query all items, query items in a specific category, and an item can have multiple categories.

Comment: Hi Brian, can i use updatechildern() to add multiple key? Beacuse i am new in android and not familiar with firestore